# backbone.js is failing with basic auth rest api

Tags: rest, backbone.js, basic-authentication

I am new to backbone.js.  I built a rest api with php and I want to connect to it with backbone.js.  I am having a tough time with passing the http basic auth that my rest api uses for authentication.

I can access my rest api easily by using curl from the command line like this

```
curl -u username:password -X GET http://api.mysite.com/user
```

But when I try to do a fetch (which is pretty much all I am trying to do) I get a response from my rest api that the authentication failed.

Here is my call from backbone.js

```
user.fetch({headers:{'Authorization':'Basic username:password'}});
```

With backbone.js I am getting back the response I would expect when the basic auth fails.  My question is, since I know my rest api with authenticate with curl, why won't it authenticate with the above javascript?

Also, when I look at the headers sent in the js console I don't see anything about Authorization.

**UPDATE**

I tried the plugin listed in the comment below but got the same result

Here is my code

```
var User=Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://api.mysite.com/user'
}); 
var user=new User();

user.credentials = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
};

user.fetch();
```

Comment: I think this answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144746/backbone-http-basic-rest-api-authentication If you want to go direcly to how the library does that, take a look here: https://github.com/fiznool/backbone.basicauth/blob/master/backbone.basicauth.js#L62

Comment: thanks @IvanSeidel, I want to try it but I don't know how to intergrate the plugin.  Do I just include the source file after I include backbone?  Or is there a different process to use plugins for backbone.

Comment: Take a look at basic Javascript libraries, or search for someone that used that specific library... But I think it's explained 'how to' on the root of the repository

Comment: I tried it, but couldn't get it to help.  I didn't see any "how to".  I included jquery, underscore and backbone first.  I am not getting any errors but I am still getting the response from my api about the login failing.  One question - There is a file in git with the plugin called bower.json.  It looks like some type of dependency file but I don't know what it is and didn't use it in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "Authorization" to the allowed headers list and that did the trick.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 3):

The username and password need to be encoded with Baes64 before being sent.

One easy way to do this (at least for testing) is to configure all jQuery ajax requests to send the info (Backbone uses jQuery for the ajax calls):

```
$.ajaxSetup(
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("USERNAME" + ":" + "PASSWORD"));
  }
);
```

Note that `btoa` is the function that will encode the params with Base64. Now you can call `user.fetch()` and it should work properly: you don't need to provide the credentials, because we've configured jQuery to send them for us (all the time).

Of course, depending on your situation (e.g. using multiple APIs), you might prefer to specify the `beforeSend` attribute within each request, or have it defined within a Backbone `sync`function.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSulc ,voted up, but that wasn't the problem.  I added my answer below.